# Git new branch is not a branch when using a previous commit

Tags: git, branch, git-commit

I was on a branch in Git, doing some work. Then I decided to check out one of my previous commits on that branch using the commit's hash, with `git checkout -b new_branch 6e559cb`. Now when I enter "git branch" it says that I'm currently on "(no branch)". How do I merge this no-branch into the branch it was split from? Thanks!

Comment: what does `git branch -avv` tell you ?

Comment: * (no branch) 4d0dcb6 tidying up
  complex     e312e49 and now, it's fixed - by using immutable hashes
  master      2cbaeb9 very basic example, no real parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somehow your command didn't create a branch at 6e559cb, you simply can create one now (where you are currently in "no branch", that is "[detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714)" mode.

```
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch
# or git checkout -b new_branch
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you did it in proper way (I am assuming that you are working on "new_branch" and you wanted to apply commit from another branch on top of that).

The most convenient way would be do cherry-pick (or merge) commit from one branch to another.

```
git[new_branch]$ git cherry-pick 6e559cb
```

Comment: Yes, I clearly screwed up something. When using your command above, isn't it required that one is on a branch? I'm currently on no branch, so don't know what to use in place of new_branch.

Comment: That's not what the OP wants to do. `git checkout -b new_branch 6e559cb` creates (and checks out) a new branch originating from commit `6e559cb`.

Comment: I see. I just used git checkout -b new_branch, without specifying the commit, but it's good to know that option exists. Thanks for the help!